# ASP.Net search subdirectory

Tags: c#, asp.net

How do I search a sub directory in my ASP.Net web site?

I know if this was a regular Winform project, I could easily get it by the following:

```
Environment.CurrentDirectory
```

or

```
System.IO.Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()
```

then

```
string[] directories = System.IO.Path.Combine(Environment.CurrentDirectory, "Portfolio")
```

How do I build the path to a subfolder called Portfolio in ASP.Net?

I'm having a problem building everything from the http://??????????/Portfolio. How do I find the ?????? part?

I tried the code above but got a completely different directory...

I don't want to hard code everything before that last subfolder because it will be different on another server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Calling `Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()` can be misleading when calling it from an ASP.NET app. The best way to do get around this is to use [`Server.MapPath()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms524632.aspx) instead, which will allow you to map a web folder to its location on disk.

So for example, running this code:

```
string path = Server.MapPath("~/Portfolio");
```

will set '`path`' equal to the location of that folder on disk.

If you're running this code from outside the context of a `Page` or control class, you won't be able to access the `Server` object directly. In this case, your code would look like this:

```
string path = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/Portfolio");
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you right, you can just access it with:

```
"/portfolio"
```

The system will concatenate "/portfolio" to the url, if, for example it is "http://site.com" you will get "http://site.com/portfolio"

If you want the physical path, you can use

```
server.mappath("/portfolio")
```

and it will return the physical directory associated (for example E:\websites\site\portfolio")

Answer (score 0):

the following piece of lines gets you to the 'bin' directory

```
Assembly asm = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
String strAppHome = Path.GetDirectoryName(asm.CodeBase).Replace("file:\\", "");
```